# data argument not used by format string for inserting data into string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When Trying to insert data into string it gives an warrning this is my whole single statement ......?what mistake exactly i didnt get ..
Any Help Will appreciated 
Thanks In advance

```
 NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO userinfo(userid,empcode,firstname,middlename,lastname,emailid,mobileno)VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",txtUserId.text,txtEmpCdoe.text, txtFname.text,txtMname.text,txtLname.text, txtEmailId.text,txtMobileNob.text,txtUserId.text ,txtRole.text,txtBrands.text,txtRegionId.text,txtZoneId.text,txtDistrictId.text,txtDealerId.text,txtDealerName.text,txtUserId.text,txtDesignation.text,txtCategoryName.text,txtProfileImageName.text,txtUserId.text,txtUserId.text,txtProfileImagePath.text];
```

Comment: amit your question is not clear.

Comment: Format it, and there is 21 "%@", and 22 "text values", so the number of placeholders don't match.

Comment: DO NOT build SQL queries using `stringWithFormat`. It's a very bad and dangerous approach.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with this (maybe there are others too) is that the number of arguments provided doesn't match the number expected by the format string. In general:

BAD:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@ ", aString, anotherString, aThirdString];

[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@ %@ %@ ", aString, anotherString];
```

OK:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@ ", aString, anotherString];
```

In your case, the following would make more sense, but please check the inputs:

```
NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO userinfo(userid,empcode,firstname,middlename,lastname,emailid,mobileno)VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",txtUserId.text,txtEmpCdoe.text,txtFname.text,txtMname.text,txtLname.text, txtEmailId.text,txtMobileNob.text];
```